# Pyspark: filter function error with .isNotNull() and other 2 other conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to filter my dataframe in Pyspark and I want to write my results in a parquet file, but I get an error every time because something is wrong with my `isNotNull()` condition. I have 3 conditions in the `filter` function, and if one of them is true the resulting row should be written in the parquet file.

I tried different versions with `OR` and `|` and different versions with `isNotNull()`, but nothing helped me.

This is one example I tried:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.filter(
    (df['col1'] == 'attribute1') |
    (df['col1'] == 'attribute2') |
    (df.where(col("col2").isNotNull()))
).write.save("new_parquet.parquet")
```

This is the other example I tried, but in that example it ignores the rows with `attribute1` or `attribute2`:

```py
df.filter(
    (df['col1'] == 'attribute1') |
    (df['col1'] == 'attribute2') |
    (df['col2'].isNotNull())
).write.save("new_parquet.parquet")
```

This is the error message:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

I hope you can help me, I'm new to the topic. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are close in second approach, I see extra single quote after `(df['col2'].isNotNull()`. May be that is throwing error. Try this `df.filter((df['col1']=='attribute1')|(df['col1']=='attribute2')|(df['col2'].isNotNull())).write.save("new_parquet.parquet")`

Comment: Apologies, I think I edited that out, as I thought that was just a typo. In the second snippet, the original post had `(df['col2'].isNotNull()')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, about the `col1` filter, you could do it using `isin`  like this:

`df['col1'].isin(['attribute1', 'attribute2'])`

And then:

`df.filter((df['col1'].isin(['atribute1', 'atribute2']))|(df['col2'].isNotNull()))`

AFAIK, the dataframe.column.isNotNull() should work, but I dont have sample data to test it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

See the example below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(3,'a'),(5,None),(9,'a'),(1,'b'),(7,None),(3,None)], ["id", "value"])
df.show()
```

The original DataFrame

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  3|    a|
|  5| null|
|  9|    a|
|  1|    b|
|  7| null|
|  3| null|
+---+-----+
```

Now we do the filter:

```
df = df.filter( (df['id']==3)|(df['id']=='9')|(~F.isnull('value')))
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  3|    a|
|  9|    a|
|  1|    b|
|  3| null|
+---+-----+
```

So you see

1. `row(3, 'a')` and `row(3, null)` are selected because of `df['id']==3'
2. `row(9, 'a')` is selected because of `df['id']==9'
3. `row(1, 'b')` is selected because of `~F.isnull('value')`, but `row(5, null)` and `row(7, null)` are not selected.